# Generating a chi-square distribution using goodness of fit test

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a chi-square distribution using a goodness of fit test.

```
null.probs=c(0.17,0.37,0.23,0.23);
chi.sq.data <- numeric()

M=1000
samp.size=740
for (k in 1:M) {
  samp.data = sample(c("Often","Some","Hardly","Never"),
                     size=samp.size,
                     replace=TRUE,
                     prob=null.probs)
  E=samp.size*null.probs;
  chi.sq.data[k] <- sum((table(samp.data)-E)^2/E)
}

hist(chi.sq.data,prob=TRUE)
```

Clearly my thinking is incorrect.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Here is the adjustment that works, thanks to the suggestions made.

```
null.probs=c(0.17,0.37,0.23,0.23);
chi.sq.data <- numeric()

M=1000
samp.size=740
for (k in 1:M) {
  samp.data = sample(c("Often","Some","Hardly","Never"),
                     size=samp.size,
                     replace=TRUE,
                     prob=null.probs)
  n.Often=sum(samp.data=="Often")
  n.Some=sum(samp.data=="Some")
  n.Hardly=sum(samp.data=="Hardly")
  n.Never=sum(samp.data=="Never")
  O=c(n.Often,n.Some,n.Hardly,n.Never)
  E=samp.size*null.probs
  chi.sq.data[k] <- sum((O-E)^2/E)
}


hist(chi.sq.data,prob=TRUE,breaks="FD")
curve(dchisq(x,3),0,max(chi.sq.data),col="red",add=TRUE)
```

And the resulting image.

[image]

Comment: I feel like you could do this directly with `?rchisq` see `?distributions` there are a lot of them built right into R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it coded you are assigning your expected values in the order `c("Often","Some","Hardly","Never")` but if you take a look at any single run notice that table has no idea what the order is so it just goes alphabetically: `c("Hardly","Never","Often","Some")`

If you actually align your expectations properly thing should work out.

But if your only goal is to generate chi-squares then `rchisq` is a better alternative.

Comment: Nice observation. I've edited my question to show the solution. I know I can use rchisq, but that was not what I wanted. The goal was not to simply draw a picture of the chisq distribution, but to show that the goodness of fit process, if applied to numerous samples, will generate an chisq distribution. Thanks to your observation, I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

@Dason is correct.  In addition, since you are generating data where the null does not hold, you would (potentially) be generating chi-squared statistics from a [non-central chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).  Furthermore, it is worth noting that the actual behavior of a chi-squared statistic can only approximate the (any) chi-squared distribution.  This is because, since your data are discrete but the distribution is continuous, there are only so many possibilities for your data to realize, but there are infinite possible values in a chi-squared distribution that cannot possibly occur in your data with your setup (albeit with N=740, the approximation should be reasonable).  For more information about this issue, it may help you to read my answer (on stats.SE) here:  [Comparing and contrasting p-values, significance levels, and type I error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33453//33500#33500).  You are best off to use [?rchisq](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Chisquare.html).